# jsf datatable inputText javascript event not getting fired

Tags: javascript, jsf, primefaces

i have jsf datatable in which javascript function not working, i called  `inputTextChanged()` in javascript from datatable but its not working...

```
        <h:dataTable value="#{order.orderList}" var="o" id="table_Details" >  
            <h:column> 
                <h:inputText value="#{o.productName}"    id="proname" name="proname"   onchange="inputTextChanged()" />
            </h:column> 
            <h:column>  
                <h:inputText value="#{o.price}"   id="proprice" name="proprice"   onchange="inputTextChanged()" /> 
            </h:column>  
        </h:dataTable>
```

and javascript

```
      function inputTextChanged()
    {  
        alert ('Event Fired');
    }
```

Comment: check your browser console, do you see some error like *no such function inputTextChanged* or some other error ? cause you probably placed the function in the wrong location...

Comment: @Daniel yeah it's showing error like, ReferenceError: inputTextChanged is not defined

Comment: place that function in a js file and include it, read more : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11988415/what-is-the-jsf-resource-library-for-and-how-should-it-be-used

Answer (score 0):

Place your code in some js file, for example `myFile.js`, then place that file in *resources* folder, under the root of your web application (same folder level with *WEB-INF*) and include it in your page in the following way:

```
<h:outputScript name="js/myFile.js" />
```

Read more here: [What is the JSF resource library for and how should it be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11988415/what-is-the-jsf-resource-library-for-and-how-should-it-be-used)

Comment: normally JavaScript working fine.if i put javascript function call in datatable its not working.